# Office Scripts last row in range

Tags: excel, scripting

I am having trouble finding how to make this conversion. For example, say I wanted to select he whole range in column G for a VBA formula, I would use:

Range(Range("G2"), Range("G2").End(xlDown)) =

For Office Scripts the closest I can come to is:

selectedSheet.getRange("G2")
.copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("G2:G2287"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values, false, false);

Any simple ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this is the thing you wanted but if you want to know the last cell in the column G you could use

```
let range = selectedSheet.getRange();
let col = range.getColumn(6).getLastCell().getAddress();
console.log(col);
```